# CORS problem with React and Entity Framework Core Web API

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been trying to do simple http request using fetch method since 2 days and I cannot rid of cors error. I put http header to .htaccess file but it doesn't seem work.

```
fetch('https://localhost:44326/api/Users', {
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ obj })
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response));
```

All the time I get information that Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing. Any ideas?

Startup configuration:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<ImageContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ImageDB"));
        });

        services.AddCors(c => c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your `startup` class configuration?

Comment: Remember to add `app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");` after `app.UseRouting()`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to set your `credentials` argument...

```
fetch('https://localhost:44326/api/Users', {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        header: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ obj })
    })
```

`same-origin` is for when the React app runs on the same domain name as the server it is fetching from.  Change it to `include` for a different domain.  Check out the fetch() API at the [Fetch() MDN Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Or, server-side, you can set the header correctly...

```
<?php

     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://mozilla.org');

?>
```

This is an example where the ReactApp would be hosted on mozilla.org.  [CORS MDN Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).  Hope this helps!

Comment: What did you try?  Setting credentials to both same-origin and include?  Did you send the header on the server side?  Did you check it with cURL to see it showing up?  Maybe try setting header to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`?

Comment: I tried everything you proposed above. Btw, I don't use php.

Comment: Clear your cache?  Could also try `credentials: omit`, and  set header origin to `*`.

Comment: Yes, I cleared and also tried variety of possibilities with credentials and header. Still cannot find solution...

Comment: Hrm, I can't think of anything else.  I reread the documentation from the links, this should be how it's supposed to work.  Headers do need to be sent before other content, but you probably know that.